# Blackberry Java: TextField *without* the caret?

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, textfield, caret, labelfield

I want a non-editable TextField (or a subclass) that doesn't even have the caret displayed. Alternatively, I want a multiline LabelField. Is any of these possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### TextField without focus cursor

```
TextField readOnly = new TextField(NON_FOCUSABLE);
readOnly.setText("Read only, no carret");
add(readOnly);
```

### TextField drawFocus override

If text is too large to fit the screen, you can override drawFocus method in TextField, so scrolling will be available:

```
TextField readOnly = new TextField(READONLY)
{
    protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on) {}
};
```

### TextFields, separated with NullFields

Other option is to split TextField into several, separated with NullFields:

```
class Scr extends MainScreen {
    public Scr() {

        String text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer "
                + "adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod "
                + "tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat "
                + "volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis "
                + "nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit "
                + "lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. "
                + "Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in "
                + "vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel "
                + "illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero "
                + "eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui "
                + "blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue "
                + "duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.";

        text = addScrollText(text, 150);
    }

    private String addScrollText(String text, int partSize) {
        while (0 < text.length()) {
            int len = Math.min(partSize, text.length());
            TextField readOnly = new TextField(NON_FOCUSABLE);
            readOnly.setText(text.substring(0, len));
            add(readOnly);
            add(new NullField());
            text = text.substring(len);
        }
        return text;
    }
}
```

### Multiline LabelField

Multiline text in LabelField, just use newline escape character:

```
String text = "first line \nnew line \nanother line";
LabelField multiLine = new LabelField(text);
add(multiLine);
```

Comment: Multiline labels are really not a problem, I had another problem that made me think it didn't work.
As for the TextField - indeed what you suggest makes a no-caret TextField; however, it's not scrollable - so if the text in the field is too long to fit on screen, it cannot be viewed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can override the paint method of each UI Element

An example:

```
public class WhiteLabelField extends LabelField 
{
    public WhiteLabelField()
    {
        super();
    }
    public WhiteLabelField(ObjectGroup text)
    {
        super(text);
    }
    public WhiteLabelField(Object text, long style)
    {
        super(text, style);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics _g)
    {
        _g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        super.paint(_g);
    }
    // Custom
    public void setSmallFontSize()
    {
        setFont( Font.getDefault( ).derive( Font.PLAIN, 16 ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a `RichTextField` with a style of `Field.NON_FOCUSABLE` and you will have what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately a `RichTextField` with the `NON_FOCUSABLE` style will not scroll if it requires more than a full screen height.